# Mockito throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unit-testing, mockito

I have these two classes(SimManager and Sim) that I want to create mock objects of and then use stub methods from them.

```
1  public class ContactTypeTest extends AndroidTestCase {
2  
3    @Override
4    public void setUp() throws Exception {
5      super.setUp();
6    
7      SimManager mockSimManager = mock(SimManager.class);
8      Sim mockSim = mock(Sim.class);
9       
10     when(mockSim.getOperator()).thenReturn("operator");
11     when(mockSim.getCircle()).thenReturn(circle);
12     when(mockSimManager.findSimBySerial("simSerial")).thenReturn(mockSim);
13    
14   }
15
16 }
```

the tests are throwing these two error traces on line no 9 above.

first:

> java.lang.VerifyError: org/mockito/cglib/core/ReflectUtils at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
>   at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>   at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
>   at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
>   at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117) at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109) at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105) at
>   org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:70) at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:85)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
>   at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26) at
>   org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51) at
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243) at
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120) at
>   in.mubble.bi.test.core.message.ContactTypeTest.setUp(ContactTypeTest.java:25)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1741)

second:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/mockito/internal/creation/jmock/ClassImposterizer$3 at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:85)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
>   at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26) at
>   org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51) at
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243) at
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120) at
>   in.mubble.bi.test.core.message.ContactTypeTest.setUp(ContactTypeTest.java:25)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1741)

I have added the `mockito-all-1.9.5.jar` in my libs folder and also added it to build paths. I don't understand whats the problem. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use ***Dexmaker***.

Take a look to this thread:

[Mockito Android dynamic proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311976/trouble-configuration-of-mockito-with-eclipse-gives-error-java-lang-verifyerro)

Comment: Now this exception trace is coming:


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.dexmaker.stock.ProxyBuilder
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.createMock(DexmakerMockMaker.java:56)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)

Comment: I am not an android expert, but it looks like you do not have the dexmaker dependencies on your classpath.

Comment: Yeah apparently i had used a wrong jar for dexmaker but now have both the jars added as given here https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/downloads/list

Comment: But now again i am getting this trace 
11-05 18:03:49.215: W/dalvikvm(2540): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/mockito/cglib/transform/AbstractProcessTask; (619)
11-05 18:03:49.215: W/dalvikvm(2540): Link of class 'Lorg/mockito/cglib/transform/AbstractProcessTask;' failed
11-05 18:03:49.220: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(2540): Cannot load class. Make sure it is in your apk. Class name: 'org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask'. Message: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask

Comment: It looks like you need to have the libraries in your apk.


Take a look to this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617610/mockito-on-android-emulator

Comment: Yeah I have been there, and I have already added all the libraries to my build and dependency paths.

Comment: This is still broken for me. 3 years later :(